# elasticsearch range query not working just gives empty response

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

In kibana I added this info to my index.

```
PUT favorite/_doc/1
{
  "first_name": "Lisa",
  "Date": "07/12/2022 16:04:30.496"
}

PUT favorite/_doc/2
{
  "first_name": "Ann",
  "Date": "07/12/2022 17:04:30.496"
}

PUT favorite/_doc/3
{
  "first_name": "Ming",
  "Date": "07/12/2022 18:04:30.496"
}
```

But when I run this query down below I get no results back. I'm not sure why this is happening and how can I fix this

```
GET favorite/_search
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "Date": {
        "gte": "07/12/2022 16:04:30.496",
        "lte": "07/12/2022 17:05:30.496"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue is that you created index without defining the explicit mapping for Elasticsearch index and your **date field is not in the format Elasticsearch supports to detect automatically**, and that way your `date` field is indexed as `text` and `keyword` as shown below

```
 "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "Date": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }

                }
```

And range query is not supported on the `text` fields, hence you are not getting result for your query.

**Solution**

Although Elasticsearch detects data field automatically but it needs to be in below formats as explained in the [official doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-field-mapping.html#date-detection)

```
[ "strict_date_optional_time","yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss Z||yyyy/MM/dd Z"]
```

**So, either you change your date format if you are not defining the explicit mapping for your index, or define explicit mapping with `date` field in the format you want to fix issue**

Comment: so in the explicit mapping I would need to get rid of the "text" and just make it "keyword"  and also how would I define the explicit mapping with date field in the format I want like I have above

Comment: @misterkevin no need to define date field as `text` or `keyword`, Elasticsearch has a `date` data type, you read more about it and supported format here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html

Comment: but I want the format to be specifically as I have it above

Comment: @misterkevin yes its possible with the use of https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html#custom-date-formats

Answer (score 0):

One quick check is the type of "Date" in the ES index mapping a datetime type with a specific format. If so the following query may be worth a try

try the boolean query

[www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)

```
GET favorite/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must":[ 
              {
                "range": {
                  "Date": {
                    "gte": "07/12/2022 16:04:30.496",
                    "lte": "07/12/2022 17:05:30.496"
                  }
                }
              }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this did not work

Comment: Ah i see ,  What do GET /favorite & GET /favorite/_mapping return.

Comment: like it just returns the mapping like I don't get why my query doesn't return data between those ranges. any idea

Comment: Is the Date field a date or text

Comment: text and keyword

Comment: that is probably why it is not working, Range queries are by default not permitted on text/keyword https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html#ranges-on-text-and-keyword